# How to increase keyboard key repeat rate on OS X?

Tags: keyboard

I know how to set the **key repeat rate** using `System Preferences > Keyboard` but it looks that the fastest settings is not enough.

Is there any way to speed up even more?

I do not know if others encountered the same issue, but I'm using a MacBook Pro, model 2010.

Comment: Good question!  I found that keyboard repeat rate seemed to be *the* factor that was causing me to experience bad vim scrolling & rendering performance in macOS; see [my comment on GitHub](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/353#issuecomment-419286706)

Comment: You can now update these settings directly in System Preferences > Keyboard > {Key Repeat, Delay Until Repeat}. More info: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/help/how-to/key-repeat/

Answer (score 368, accepted):

You can also change the preference keys by running the following in Terminal:

```
defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat -int 10 # normal minimum is 15 (225 ms)
defaults write -g KeyRepeat -int 1 # normal minimum is 2 (30 ms)
```

The changes aren't applied until you log out and back in. KeyRepeat can't be set between 2 (30 ms) and 1 (15 ms) though.

I also use KeyRemap4MacBook. I've set the repeat rates to 40 ms and the initial repeat rates to 150 ms.

Comment: I can't believe it took me so long to look for the answer. This is amazing. Also, I did not have to log out and back in with Yosemite.

Comment: This answer worked for me. Note that 10 is very fast. I found 12 similar to what I use in Windows.

Comment: Regretting the wasted time of a decade. 

Comment: Looks like I had to do this again after upgrading to macOS Sierra.

Comment: How do you determine how many milliseconds a value is? Are they just 15ms multiplied by the defaults value? How did you determine that, or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: one note you might miss in the answer - **log out/in or restart your machine to have changes take effect**

Comment: Make sure you don't set `InitialKeyRepeat` to a rate that is too fast. I experienced an issue where suddenly every key press caused every key to double the input. For example, pressing the "a" key once would input "aa". This effectively made it impossible to login as I was unable to input my password correctly. I believe I was able to get around the issue by booting in safe-boot mode, I revisited this page by going through my browser's history, selecting and pasting the command `defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat -int 10` into iTerm and restarting the Mac.

Comment: Works perfectly fine on macOS High Sierra

Comment: Mojave update: I find these two commands are still needed for me, as the default values (as well as their max values as settable through the UI) are still not good for me. I'm not sure about the default values though, because personally I use KeyRepeat=2 and InitialKeyRepeat=15. Also, to make the update effective, I _had_ to logout/login.

Comment: Putting to sleep and back is enough, no need to restart, re-login

Comment: God bless you, still working on macOS Catalina

Comment: Moving to linux I found that `xset r rate 225 33` is about the same as the above defaults. Its amasing how much impact small things like this have on workflows.

Comment: BTW, which is which? On Catalina I have `Key Repeat` and `Delay Until Repeat`

Comment: Any idea how to avoid having to logout/restart to have this change take effect?  When you use the UI to change this it takes effect immediately without any delay.  There must be some way to get macOS to re-read this configuration value.

Comment: If you don't want to log out/in, you can alternatively switch to another user and switch back (or log out the other user and log back into same running user).

Comment: I come to this answer every time I need to set up a MacBook.  Much love.

Comment: Reporting that on Big Sur, logging out and back in is required for the change to take effect. Also: don't go lower than 10 (150ms) on InitialKeyRepeat, you maniac (future me).

Comment: Time wasted over a decade = `30ms wasted per repeated key X 10% of all keypresses are repeated X 10k keystrokes per hour X 8 hours per day X 5/7 days per week X 365 per year X 10 years = 7 days` thus not the end of the world.

Comment: Note that you may also want to first run `defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` so that you can repeat the key in all apps in the first place.

Comment: I've run the above commands but when I press and hold the enter key on my MacBook (macOS Big Sur), the repeat is still very slow. I've also restarted my MacBook. Are these instructions still valid?

Comment: Ok this solved my issue https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411531/increase-keyrepeat-speed-in-macos-big-sur#comment630237_411618

Answer (score 26):

I just discovered that I had [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) installed and inside this application you have lots of low level settings for key repeat.

Now I'm happy with 400ms initial repeat time and 20ms repeat wait.

Comment: I have the same problem on OSX Lion on an iMac: the max repeat speed in System Preferences > Keyboard is insufficient (I use vim where fast repeated keystrokes really speed up navigation - but the faster speed is also useful in browsers).  Thx for the KeyRemap4MacBook tip - works great.

Comment: This app has been renamed `Karabiner` and the options for Key Repeat are currently in the top row of tabs under "Key Repeat" between "Change Key" and "Status Message".  Works great, was able to reduce it too far and bump it back up to sanity.

Comment: Does Karabiner still have this function? I can't find it anywhere. There's no "Key Repeat" tab.

Comment: OIC it existed in Karabiner, but not in Karabiner Elements. But Karabiner doesn't seem to have any effect on Sierra.

Comment: Came here to confirm that Karabiner "Elements" (the latest version) does not support setting the key repeat rate, as it used to. See [this](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1046#issuecomment-348247220).

Comment: `KeyRemap4MacBook` (or the renamed Karabiner) no longer supports it. The accepted solution is the best way. Remember to log off

Answer (score 11):

Old post, but this may help someone: If you are using the "Karabiner app" (https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) which is a third party app commonly used to remap keys (or make OS X keyboard mimic some of Windows keyboards behaviors) it will bypass your OS X configurations.

If you are using it, to increase your keyboard rate you should go to the app and on the second tab ("Key Repeat") you'll find the option Repeat Rate. Changing that will render immediate effect and, as far as I can tell, it's the only way to get the repeat rate changed when using this app.

Comment: FYI: KeyRemap4MacBook was renamed to Karabiner

Comment: I cannot find the "Key Repeat" option in version 11.1.0. Where is it? https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1046

Comment: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/help/how-to/key-repeat/

Comment: @SebastiánPalma quite cool to see that https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/help/how-to/key-repeat/ points to this question! You can get a stack overflow in your brain navigating back and forth ;)

Answer (score 1):

@user495470's answer is great for native apps, but for whatever reason, it appears to have messed up key repeat for me in XQuartz windows.  To work around the issue, I initially ran this in the terminal:

```
xset r rate <initial wait> <number of repeated strokes per second>
```

Leaving off the last 2 arguments will reset the system defaults.

I read that you have to run this command every time you run XQuartz anew, but when I put it in my login script, it caused the system to hang on shutdown (until I killed the hung xset commands) and on startup, so I discovered that a better way to change the key repeat setting is to first disable the little bubble menu that appears above a typed character upon press & hold, e.g. hold down the a key and you are presented with a bubble containing alternate 'a' characters with various umlauts, accents, etc..:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

*Then* run the key repeat commands:

```
defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat -int 10 # normal minimum is 15 (225 ms)
defaults write -g KeyRepeat -int 1 # normal minimum is 2 (30 ms)
```

If you do it this way, key repeats will work in XQuartz windows without needing to run `xset r # #`.