# Increase KeyRepeat Speed in MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, keyboard, big-sur

It seems like the method to increase the key repeat speed further than
the settings allow as mentioned in this question no longer works in Big Sur:

[How to increase keyboard key repeat rate on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10467/how-to-increase-keyboard-key-repeat-rate-on-os-x)

Has anyone figured out a way to increase the Key Repeat speed in Big Sur?

Answer (score 8):

```bsh
defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 1
defaults write NSGlobalDomain InitialKeyRepeat -int 10
```

And turn off press and hold if you haven't: \

```bsh
defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

I can confirm they work because I am using these settings. Also make sure "slow keys" is disabled in *System Preferences > Accessibility > Slow Keys*.

Also, although it seems counterintuitive, I checked all my defaults for keyrepeat entries with `defaults read | grep -i 'keyrepeat'` and found that I had "KeyRepeatEnabled = 0;" in my com.apple.Accessibility defaults.
So maybe setting that to 1 would override the other above defaults and prevent fast key repeat.

To match my setting you can use the command:

```bsh
defaults write com.apple.Accessibility KeyRepeatEnabled -bool 0
```

You need to restart your computer for all of these things to take effect! Logging off and on did not change anything for me.

Comment: Are you running **macOS Big Sur**?

Comment: @user3439894 yes

Comment: Confirming this working. Running BigSur Air M1

Comment: `-bool 0` doesn't work for me, but `-bool false`.

`defaults write com.apple.Accessibility KeyRepeatEnabled -bool false`

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to check slow keys being off ( "System Preferences > Accessibility > Slow Keys"). That's what was blocking me the whole time.