# Slow delete key repeat

Tags: macos, keyboard

[image]

I've adjusted the `Key Repeat` to as fast as possible and `Delay Until Repeat` to as short as possible, and restarted (many times), yet holding delete for example to delete long lines of text is still painfully sloooooooooow.

I'm on macOS 11.6 and also recorded a video of how slow this is https://youtu.be/W3JMXTMTxRQ

I've tried this in multiple applications from notes, to the terminal to IntelliJ.

I know there are some workarounds like option+delete, but is this really the fastest repeat possible when holding down a key?

Comment: Do other buttons such as backspace behave properly (faster)?

Comment: This is 10 years old, but may work for you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10467/how-to-increase-keyboard-key-repeat-rate-on-os-x

Comment: Sadly, it didn't change anything :( How can this bug exist on such a mainstream product, sigh