# Control + Space switch to third keyboard in previous list, without waiting for selection popup

Tags: macos, keyboard, monterey

I currently have 5 configured keyboards.

Pressing `Ctrl` + `Space` lets me immediately switch to the previous keyboard without delay.

When I press `Ctrl` + two times `Space` in quick succession I expect it to go back by two keyboards (the third entry in the list), but in fact it behaves the same as if I pressed `Space` only a single time and only goes to the previous keyboard.

If I want to go to the third or later keyboard I have to wait for around a second for the 'keyboard selection popup' to appear, which puts me at the correctly counted offset, meaning that the OS actually counted my extra presses, but choses to ignore them before this delay. So if I pressed `Space` two times, it will be at the third entry, or at the fourth entry if I pressed three times, but if I don't wait for the popup it will switch to the second keyboard entry regardless.

I want to be able to switch to the third+ keyboard in the previous keyboards list, without having to wait that one extra second for the popup.

Is this possible?

**Illustrating image:**

This is how the keyboard selection popup appears after I pressed `Space` three times, and then waited a second.

[image: keyboard selection popup after three Space presses and waiting]

- If I would not have waited it would have selected the second keyboard "美國"
- If I wait as I did in the image and then let go, it selects the fourth keyboard "拉丁美洲"

I'm on Monterrey 12.6.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the repeat and delay settings in system preferences > keyboard > keyboard?

Comment: Maybe check out an alternative switcher like https://github.com/hatashiro/kawa

Comment: I already have increased my key repeat rate with this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/83923/401854 - it does not seem to affect this issue though!

The alternative switcher looks great, thanks for the link - I'll try it out!